# C++ subordinate constants

Tags: c++, identifier, c++14

I have a fixed set of domain specific categories. Each category is identified by a relevant constant value (useful in itself) of enumerable type. Besides, each category has a fixed set of subcategories. Each subcategory is to be identified by a relevant constant value (also useful), unique within this category, but NOT unique across the categories.

I'm trying to find a way to declare identifiers for my subcategories, 'subordinate' to identifiers for the categories, i.e. such that a subcategory identifier could be accessed via related category identifier, with compile-time resolution.

What is the appropriate way to do this in C++14?

Identifiers are just constant values of enumerable type (let it be int-based).

Here is what I tried:

```
enum Category
{
  One = 1,
  Two = 2,
  Three = 3
};

template<Category categoryName> struct Subcategory;

template<> struct Subcategory<Category::One>
{
  enum
  {
    A = 0,
    B = 1
  };
};
```

We can access a subcategory identifier via `Subcategory<Category::One>::A` (not a thrill...)

The expression looks too long, and I'm trying to find a solution yielding somewhat more concise expression for access to A. The last resort along this path is making the first enumeration unnamed...

Actually, as pepper_chico noted, the expression is reduced to `Subcategory<One>::A`.
Is there a solution (probably not template-based) that would allow to get rid of identifier `Subcategory`, leaving just `One` and `A`?

Comment: Please post a minimal example of what you have tried and what problems you encountered. It would be much easier to help you if we see what structure your classes (or whatever your "categories" map to in c++) have. Also, something tells me you have something specific in mind when you say "identifier". Do you mean the name of a type, class, enum, function, ...? Run-time, compile-time?

Comment: As you're not using an `enum class` you can turn `Subcategory<Category::One>::A` into `Subcategory<One>::A` without problems, isn't it enough?

Comment: I always simply used `One_A`, `One_B`.  Is there a reason you don't want that?

Comment: pepper_chico - Yes. It seems I just overlooked it. :)

Comment: Mooing Duck - The reason is just my desire to avoid duplicating `One` in identifiers for subcategories (and name of the category identifier may be longer, of course).

Comment: I dunno category theory, so I'm trying to grasp your problem without knowing it. There may be other better approaches than yours to the same problem. Regarding your last request, you could do `using SubOne = Subcategory<One>;`, you would just be generating an alias though.

Comment: With that `using`, needed for every subcategorization, you could then access stuff with `SubOne::A`, `SubTwo::A`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of an odd hack, but by defining objects that correspond to categories you can enable the syntax `One.A` for subcategory names ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e4cf9f5228e1c7d)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Category
{
  One = 1,
  Two = 2,
  Three = 3
};

template <Category> struct CategoryDescriptor;

#define DECLARE(name,...) \
template <> \
struct CategoryDescriptor<Category::name> { \
  enum sub_type { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
  constexpr operator Category() const { return Category::name; } \
}; \
constexpr CategoryDescriptor<Category::name> name{}

DECLARE(One, A, B);
DECLARE(Two, C, D);
DECLARE(Three, A, C, E);

#undef DECLARE

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Category c) {
    return os << static_cast<std::underlying_type<Category>::type>(c);
}

template <Category C>
using SubCategoryOf = typename CategoryDescriptor<C>::sub_type;

int main() {
    std::cout << "One = " << One << "\n"
                 "One.A = " << One.A << "\n"
                 "Two = " << Two << "\n"
                 "Two.D = " << Two.D << "\n"
                 "Three = " << Three << "\n"
                 "Three.A = " << Three.A << '\n';

    // Category names convert to Category
    auto foo = [](Category){};
    foo(Three);

    // Subcategory names convert to SubCategoryOf<Category>
    auto bar = [](SubCategoryOf<Two>){};
    bar(Two.C);
}
```

Comment: Well... Yes, it solves the problem (at least formally). Sorry I can't vote up yet due to the rules here at SO...